# Solving a substitution cipher

Tags: cryptography

I am looking for a way to use *Mathematica* to decipher cipher texts that have been encrypted with a simple substitution cipher. Last week, our teacher worked the board on the following cipher.

*VKQXSKHQKNKIZNKTZOKYYHQXTHKTZIHQKAZYHWACZNHXTHOKHHKN
YNKCNKYKTHKFXTFWHVWOORKGTTKUKYYXNBHZCNZUKKFVWHQHQK
FKHXWOYZIHQKYZOGHWZTWQXSKYXWFKTZGPQHZUZTSWTUKBZGHQ
XHUWCQKNYZIHQWYTXHGNKXNKNKXFWOBYZOGROKXTFHZPWSKBZG
YZAKWTYWPQHWTHZHQKNXHWZTXOKZIHQKWNFKSKOZCAKTHRGHRK
XYYGNKFHQXHHQKYCKUWAKTRKIZNKGYXCCKNHXWTYHZHQKSKNBYW
ACOKYHYCKUWKYZIUNBCHZPNXCQWHTZVZTOBNKAXWTYHZPWSKBZG
HQKIGOOHNXTYOXHWZTZIHQKUQXNXUHKNYGCZTHQKCXNUQAKTHXY
GTNWFFOKF*

What we basically did were to use sites such as [this one](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/text-characterisation/monogram-bigram-and-trigram-frequency-counts/) to do the counting and then we ourselves had to do the actually substitution. I would very much like to see a solution that removed that step.

I have seen that Jon McLoone's solution but my attempts to implement it have failed miserably (see http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/01/26/breaking-secret-codes-with-mathematica/). Anyone willing to take a stab?

Comment: Welcoem! Can you show us what you tried so far (what about Jon´s implementation)? That is always a good way to avoid coding service sentiments.

Comment: Something like `WE HAVE THEREFORE NO LESS THAN TEN OF THE MOST IMPORTANT LETTERS REPRESENTED AND IT WILL BE UNNECESSARY TO PROCEED WITH THE DETAILS OF THE SOLUTION I HAVE SAID ENOUGH TO CONVINCE YOU THAT CIPHERS OF THIS NATURE ARE READILY SOLUBLE AND TO GIVE YOU SOME INSIGHT INTO THE RATIONALE OF THEIR DEVELOPMENT BUT BE ASSURED THAT THE SPECIMEN BEFORE US APPERTAINS TO THE VERY SIMPLEST SPECIES OF CRYPTOGRAPH IT NOW ONLY REMAINS TO GIVE YOU THE FULL TRANSLATION OF THE CHARACTERS UPON THE PARCHMENT AS UNRIDDLED`

Comment: But of course I won't show my code unless you show a good deal of effort first

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.